# Do I need copyright notice on CI related code?

Tags: github, license-notice

The project has files related to CI/CD process in its repository, such as Travis-CI and GitHub Actions configurations.

Can they be classified as source code? Should I put copyright notice into them (all other files (*.java, *.xml, etc) in the project have copyright notice).

Comment: Where are you putting your notice now? Normally, you place a notice at the root of the project tree, such as LICENSE.txt. You do not need to place the notice into each file.

Comment: It doesn't matter for copyright puposes if it is C source code, a shell script or the text of your latest SciFi novel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copyright notices are not *required*, but it would be reasonably common to add such notices to scripts and config files as well. There is no fundamental difference between a Java program, a shell script, and an actions.yml file.

Those individual files may or may not be copyrightable in your jurisdiction, but we can't know that up front. If a project has a policy of using such copyright notices, put them everywhere.